# Use google Cloud Datastore to share data between all users

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

Ok, so in this scenario we have three users that download my app: Mike, Suzy, and John. I want to store an Entity object on the Datastore using this code, for each user:

```
        DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Entity e = new Entity("Person",someKey);
        e.setProperty("name",name);
        e.setProperty("age",age);
        ds.put(e);
```

So when the three users named above use my app for the first time, my Google Cloud Datastore shows three entities of kind, "Person" with name properties: "Mike", "Suzy", and "John", and the cooresponding age properties.

Lets say that John opens the app and wants to see who else is using the app, how can I get those entities and display them to john so that he sees Suzy and Mike's names?

Basically, I want to be able to share data between all users by storing entities on the Datastore, and granting access to other users' entities to every user.

Another scenario could be an implementation of a High Scores list: Let's say I only want to keep the top 5 all time high scores across all users:

```
        Entity e2 = new Entity("HiScore",aKey);
        e.setProperty("score",score);
        ds.put(e);
```

So when a user gets a new score, I would pull all existing entities, check the score properties on all of them and update the datastore accordingly by replacing a score. At the same time, I'd also want this data update pushed to other devices.

So here are two general examples along the lines of what I would like to accomplish (I know about google-play API that handles high scores for you, so don't tell me to use that because I'm not necessarily trying to implement high scores). In short I want to create a feed of the current entities that exist on my Datastore that can be seen by all users

Is using datastore entities the right way to go for this?

Comment: I agree with @tx802's answer, that should pretty much cover it. Even though you have already discarded I really recommend taking a deeper look into Google play services, its not just a high score API, it has dozens ok kickass APIs to handle interactions between users you'll most likely will be needing.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong approach. Cloud datastore is a datastore. Everything you mentioned in your question is an application level issue.  I would have posted this as an answer, but it's not an answer, it's a recommendation. You would need to implement data sharing at the application level, not in the database. If you come from an RDBMS background, you might have implemented this at the database level, but in the cloud storage world this is implemented in the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question (or set of questions), but to answer some of your individual points:

> Lets say that John opens the app and wants to see who else is using the app, how can I get those entities and display them to john so that he sees Suzy and Mike's names?

That's a very simple query, like this:

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query q = new Query("Person");
List<Entity> persons = ds.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

You then say

> I want to be able to share data between all users by storing entities on the Datastore, and granting access to other users' entities to every user

Users don't own entities; your Cloud Platform project owns entities.  So it's up to your application to determine who can see what data.  There's nothing inherent in Datastore preventing Suzy from seeing Mike's `Person` entity unless your application puts rules in place.

Finally,

> Another scenario could be an implementation of a High Scores list: Let's say I only want to keep the top 5 all time high scores across all users...
>
> ... So when a user gets a new score, I would pull all existing entities, check the score properties on all of them and update the datastore accordingly by replacing a score.

Depending on your traffic you may find that solution doesn't scale well; I would recommend reading [this case study](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/fast-and-reliable-ranking-in-datastore/).